How to Have Safe4337 Pay for Gas Fees with Safe Funds in transactions
I’m working on a solution to ensure Safe4337 pays for gas fees using the Safe’s funds, not the signers’ funds. Here’s my use case and some questions:
Use case

Sponsoring Safe Deployment: We’re using Pimlico to sponsor the deployment of a Safe, as we don’t expect users to pay for Safe creation.
Paying Gas Fees with Safe Funds: After the Safe is deployed, we want all subsequent transactions (ETH, ERC-20, ERC-721) to have gas fees deducted directly from the Safe funds.

What We Know So Far

Safe4337 Default Behavior:
According to the docs, Safe4337 automatically deducts transaction fees in the native token (e.g., ETH) directly from the Safe account, provided there are sufficient funds. As stated in the relay kit docs


By default, the transaction fees will be paid in the native token and extracted from the Safe account, so there must be enough funds in the Safe address.


Pimlico 0.6 Entry Point:
Safe4337 currently supports Pimlico’s 0.6 Entry Point. However, we’ve tested this and observed a 5-6x increase in gas fees when using the 0.6 Entry Point.
Pimlico 0.7 Entry Point:
There’s a newer version (0.7 Entry Point) that is significantly more efficient, with substantially lower fees.
Running the getSupportedEntryPoints() method in Safe4337 confirms that the 0.7 Entry Point is recognized. However, the Relay Kit documentation indicates that Entry Point 0.7 is not yet supported.


Questions
So I this leaves me with a couple of questions here:

How can I ensure the Safe4337 pays for gas fees directly from its funds without relying on Pimlico or any bundler (after the deployment)? And not have to rely on Pimlico's (or any other bundler's) estimations?
Is there a way of using the 0.7 entry point by Pimlico? I've ran the getSupportedEntryPoints() method in the Safe4337, and I actually see the address of the 0.7 entry point. However, I also realize that in the relay-kit docs, it says that the 0.7 version is not yet supported.
Is there any other solution we're not seeing to achieve our objective?


To be very clear on the objective, what we are looking for is a way of having the Safe pay for the fees with its funds (and not the signers' funds).
All the best and thanks in advance!
